# ElasticSearch NEST - Using client.Get to get search for a document across all indexes

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Using NEST v6.4.2

I need to use the client.Get API to fetch a document which searches across ALL indices instead of one index.

My code looks as follows:

```
   var client = // intiialize elasticsearch client here
   var id = // some document id

   // the call to client.Get below fails as "" is not a valid index name
   // I have also tried passing "*", Indicies.All, Indices.AllIndices, etc but nothing works

   var document = client.Get<dynamic>(new GetRequest("", "_all", id));
```

Has anyone done this before? Documentation seems to show that you can do this using the client.Search API but this is not optimal for retrieving a single document so I would like to avoid if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/multi-index.html) for elasticsearch 6.x

> Single index APIs such as the Document APIs and the single-index alias
>   APIs do not support multiple indices.

but you can do term query on `_id` field to retrieve documents based on id

```
var response = await client.SearchAsync<dynamic>(s => s
    .AllIndices()
    .AllTypes()
    .Query(q => q.Term("_id", "1")));
```

Hope that helps.